# Why implicitly call of the inner class instance not allowed?

Tags: groovy

I use groovy 2.4.18

A parent and inner child classes:

```
class Parent {
    def name
    def child = new Child()
    def call() {
        println('parent called')
    }
    class Child {
        def call() {
            println('child called')
        }
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
import base.Parent

parent = new Parent(name: 'parent')
parent()
parent.child.call()
parent.child()
```

output:

```
parent called
child called
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: base.Parent.child() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: call(), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), getChild(), setChild(java.lang.Object), split(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Comment: Worth noting that this is not because `Child` is an inner class in `Parent`. It's broken even if `Child` is made a top-level class or a `static` nested class in `Parent`. I got it to run using **`parent['child']()`**. And I saw no documented limitation on this syntax, so it could be just a parsing gotcha or bug.

Comment: This also works: `(parent.child)()`

Comment: @zett42 yes, here is a couple of workarounds. Also i've got an anwer from jira:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9418?focusedCommentId=17042700&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17042700

Answer (score 1):

This should be a bug. I am not 100% as we may have redefined when automatic expansion to call is valid (assigning child to a local variable x and then doing x() will work for example), but I would still suggest to enter an issue for this in the Apache Groovy JIRA.